# Find number of decimal representations with no consecutive $1$ and $2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, generating-functions

Let $a_n$ be the number of decimal numbers with no two consecutive $1$ and $2$.

We may find this number using generating function. But first of all we should write representation of all decimal numbers with consecutive $1$ and $2$ (let it be $b_{n})$, and $a_n = 9\cdot 10^{n-1} - b_{n}$.

We may represent it using $\{0\} , \dots , \{9\}$. So for $b_{n}$ we have sequence $(1\cup \dots \cup 9 \cup \{\emptyset\})(12(0 \cup \dots \cup9)^{*})^{*}$, we may compute generating function corresponding to this sequence. $F(x) = \frac{(1+9x)(1-10x)}{1-10x-x^2}$. Now if we represent it with series we have that $a_{n} = \frac{(454 - 89 \sqrt{26}) (5 + \sqrt{26})^n - (5 - \sqrt{26})^n (454 + 89 \sqrt{26})}{2 \sqrt{26}}$.

First 3 numbers are valid, but for $n = 4$, $a_n = 191$, instead of $279$ (number of $4$-decimal numbers with consecutive $1$ and $2$).

Maybe there is a problem with my sequence-notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something wrong with your generating function. Let's compute $a(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n$.

We denote by $D=\{0,1,\ldots,9\}$ the set of digits, and by $A_n\subseteq D^n$ our sets (with $|A_n|=a_n$) of $n$-digit numbers with no consecutive $1$ and $2$, viewed as words of length $n$ over $D$. Clearly, $a_1=9$ (the elements of $A_1$ are one-letter words over $D\setminus\{0\}$); for the following induction step to be correct, we assume that $A_0$ consists of the (single) empty word, so that $a_0=1$. Now, for $a\in D^n$ and $b,c\in D$, we have $abc\in A_{n+2}$ if and only if $ab\in A_{n+1}$ and $bc\neq 12$; note that if $bc=12$ we still have $ab\in A_{n+1}\iff a\in A_n$: $$A_{n+2}=(A_{n+1}\cdot D)\ \setminus\ (A_n\cdot\{12\})\implies a_{n+2}=10a_{n+1}-a_n,$$ which gives $a(x)=\color{blue}{\dfrac{1-x}{1-10x+x^2}}=1+9x+89x^2+881x^3+\underbrace{8721}_{=9000-\color{red}{279}}x^4+86329x^5+\ldots$

Comment: I understand that my g.f. is wrong, but I don't know where is the problem. I've tried to solve opposite problem, and find number of decimal numbers with $12$. But my method have broken somewhere.

Comment: @openspace: It seems you're double-counting sequences like $12\ldots$.

Comment: Why I double-count them? I've thought that I don't count them all.

Comment: my bad. That's true. Is it possible to construct regular expression for your case.

Comment: (I've removed my comment - the correct "ambiguous" example would be $1212$.)

Comment: @openspace: For counting, you need not just *any* regular expression, but the one with an *unambiguous* matching. That is, you need a [DFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton). It is certainly possible to build it, but I'm definitely too lazy for that ;)

Comment: I'll try to make it. Thank's!

Answer (score 1):

I liked metamorphy's explanation.

The same problem can be solved with matrices.

- Let $c_n$ be the number of $n$ digit numbers containing a 1 followed by a 2.
- Let $d_n$ be the number of $n$ digit numbers with a last digit (mod 10) of 1 excluding numbers containing a 1 followed by a 2,
- And let $e_n$ be the number of $n$ digit numbers excluding those that have a 1 followed by a 2 and excluding the numbers that end in a 1.

The numbers you are looking for are $a_n = d_n+e_n= 9\cdot10^n- c_n$, the number of $n$ digit numbers that do not contain a 1 followed by a 2.

These three sequences obey $c_{n+1} = 10 c_n + d_n$, $d_{n+1} = d_n + e_n$, and $e_n = 8 d_n + 9 e_n$, so 
$$
\left(\begin{matrix} c_{n+1}\\d_{n+1}\\e_{n+1}\end{matrix}\right) = 
B\left(\begin{matrix} c_n\\d_n\\e_n\end{matrix}\right)
$$
where 
$$B = \left(\begin{matrix} 10 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 8 & 9\end{matrix}\right).$$
Now it is pretty easy to compute the sequences with
$$
\left(\begin{matrix} c_n\\d_n\\e_n\end{matrix}\right) = B^{n-1} \left(\begin{matrix} 0\\1\\8\end{matrix}\right).
$$

Comment: I don't understand your definition of $d_n$

Comment: Let $C_n$ be the set of $n$ digit numbers which contain a 1 followed by a 2, and let $O_n$ be the set of $n$ digit numbers ending in 1, then $d_n= \left|C_n\setminus O_n \right| $, the size of the set of numbers which are in $C_n$ but are not in $O_n$.  Does that help?